# Indri Lemur: issue with the make file

Tags: c++, makefile, full-text-indexing

I want to compile my indri lemur application, so i've created a folder with myapp.cpp and copied Makefile.app.in from the indri root directory to myApp/Makefile.app as explained here: [Write your own app](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/lemur/wiki/Using%20the%20API%20to%20Write%20Your%20Own%20Application)

However when I run make, I get the following errors. Is this an error specific to the toolkit or is about the compiler ?

```
P-MacBook-Pro:myapp aneuryzma$ make -f Makefile.app
g++ @DEFS@ @CPPFLAGS@ @CXXFLAGS@ -I@includedir@ myapp.cpp -o myapp  -L@libdir@ @LDFLAGS@ -lindri @LIBS@
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: @DEFS@: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: @CPPFLAGS@: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: @CXXFLAGS@: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: myapp.cpp: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: @LDFLAGS@: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: @LIBS@: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link states that you should copy Makefile.app, not Makefile.app.in.

You need (usually) a configure-script to build ordinary Makefiles from .in files.

Comment: thanks, however I still have an error: indri/Repository.hpp:22:32: error: indri/Parameters.hpp: No such file or directory. The reason is that the included file, includes other files in the same directory but it still uses indri/ as prefix, and this is unnecessary...

Comment: What is the value of _includedir_?